What does 設定盛りすぎだ mean here?
This is from the anime Noragami, with a girl teasing another girl about how she is very tired (鯨飲中学生 refers to either that she got into some accident via drinking and thus was sleepy or was just a joke on how sleepy she was that day, though I don't remember well. I don't know where the translation of "performance artist" came from), as well as how she is a hidden fan of martial arts:

隠れ格闘技オタクで鯨飲中学生って
明らかに設定盛り過ぎだわこの子
A closet martial arts nerd
and a performance artist still in school?
Talk about having a bunch
on your plate. (show's translation)

I am having a hard time understanding what 設定 means in this context.
One of the definitions of 設定 is not very helpful:

ある目的に沿って、新たに物事をもうけ定めること。

The girl is establishing being both a hidden fan of martial arts and being a heavy drinker in middle school?
And with some kind of goal of these combined activities as well? I don't see how this definition fits with the usage here.


設定 refers to any interesting trait or backstory that characterizes a fictional person. For example, キャラの設定を決める means "deciding the character's backstory/profile/attributes/etc." It's similar in meaning to 属性 ("trait" as in moe trait) but is a little broader.
Unless there is a school named "Gei-in Middle School", 鯨飲中学生 means "heavy-drinking middle school student". I don't know why it's been translated completely differently, but it might be because a drinking child was deemed inappropriate (even as fiction) for a western audience.
盛る means "to stack up", and -過ぎ means "over-" or "too much".

A literal translation is something like this:

A closet martial arts otaku, and a heavy-drinking middle schooler? This girl's backstory is obviously over the top.

Of course, she's not saying someone "designed" this otaku girl; she is saying this as a joke, implying "You're too unique even if you were a fictional character!" Real people who excel in many diverse fields or have many unique episodes are sometimes jokingly admired as being 設定盛りすぎ.
